# Easy Auth Implicit Flow with AAD and Azure Function returns Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal, implicit-flow

**API repro**

- I created a simple azure function app in azure portal and function with http binding. Function just returns string "Hello from secured API".
- Next in platform features I selected *Authentication/Authorization*. I turned on app service authentication. I selected action to take when request not authenticated: *Log in with AAD*. Selected AAD as my provider and configured in Express mode (Default Directory) and selected {name} for new Active Directory App.
- I also added to CORS policy address: *http://localhost:8080* where my Vue.js client app is running.
- After those operations I had registered app in my AAD with *user_impersonation* scope already defined. AD App had already configured redirect URI: https://{name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback, checked Id token for implicit grant on Web platform. I wanted to change supported account types to multitenant, but I cannot due to some error.
- In Expose Api section I changed App Id Uri from https://{name}.azurewebsites.net to api://{app id} in order to choose multitenant supported client types. There already has been user_impersonation scope defined.

**client repro**

- I registered my app on Web platform with redirect uri *http://localhost:8080/* and select both id and access token uder Implicit Grant section. I chose multitenant account type.
- I added api permission to my API (azure function) *api://{api app id }/user_impersonation*
- I am using MSAL.JS in my vue.app. I've done all my job there. Got popup, gave my login and password.
- I received id token and access token in my vue.js client app from Identity provider (AAD).
- I am sending request to my API (azure function) with Authorization header Bearer {access_token}.

**Problem**

My API request is unauthorized. I got status 401:

```
POST https://{azure func name}.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code={code}== 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Http address was copied from azure portal.

When I click link, I am redirected to log in and next redirected to to azure function with my "Hello from secured API" text in brwoser tab.

I seems that Easy auth treat my azure function as Client App, whether I want it to be middleware APi for my vue.js app. My Azure function API should only recieve and validate access tokens.

**Tried**

I also tried to sent request from postman with the token, but also received unauthorized.

I explored the token and it seems to be correct:

```
"aud": "api://{Azure function App Id (id in AAD)}",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenant id}/",
"appid": "{registered vue js client app id (id in AAD)}",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the problem I had to go to Authentication/Authorization section in my Azure Function App platform features. Under Authentication provider select AAD -> advanced and add allowed token audience: api://{Azure Function AD App Id }.

The problem was that my token was intended for other audience: `https://{func name}.azurewebsites.net`. It was due to changing my AF AD App Id:

> "In Expose Api section I changed App Id Uri from
>   https://{name}.azurewebsites.net to api://{app id} in order to choose
>   multitenant supported client types. There already has been
>   user_impersonation scope defined."

This operation also has changed scope names.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your answer. I was preparing a similar question when I found your answer. "allowed token audience" was the one config I did not know. You saved me a couple of hours ;)

Comment: Nice to know that I help you . I wasted a couple of hours then

Comment: Thank you very much @zolty13 It is working :)
First I could not find this setting. Later I found it here:
Function App -> Authentication -> Edit Identity provider Microsoft -> The last field in the opening form is "Allowed token audiences"